# Is it possible to copy an object's properties from one component and display them in another component using refs?

Tags: html, reactjs, dom

Say I have 2 components. One is a table with a list of stores. Each store has properties like color, item, open, closed. The other component is one to create a store.

I want to be able to click on a little copy icon on one of the created stores already, and take that information to the create store component, and populate that component with the properties in order to make changes and create a completely new store.

Is this doable using refs? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Use ref to this task is a mistake. React works using a Virtual DOM that is a cleaner and faster Object Tree with information that will be through to DOM by React DOM the REF API is used to access direct the DOM information, and you don't need any information from DOM to do ur task.

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

A way yo do what you describe is create a state/setState on the parent component and pass a state for the store component and a setState to the table component for example:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const StoreComponenet = ({ color, item, open})=>{
  // logic of component
  return (
    <div> 
      // ...
    </div>

  )
}


const TableComponent = ({ setStore })=>{
  // logic of component
  return (
    <table>
      <tr onClick={() => setStore("blue", {id: 2, name: "BlueStore" }, false)}>
        Build blue store
      </tr>
      ...
   </table>

  )
}

const App = ()=>{
  const [store, setStore] = useState(null)

  return (

    <TableComponent setStore={setStore} />

    {
      store && 
        <StoreComponent 
          color={store?.color} 
          item={store?.item} 
          open={store?.open} 
        />
    }

  )

}
```